# how to use hover with animate.css lib?

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-animations

I have many elements like this in one page.

```
<?php for($i=0;$i<100;$i++):?>
     <div class="parent">
        <span class="child"></span>
     </div>
<?php endif;?>
```

I want when a user hover on a specific div.psrent, I could add a new class to div.child with jQuery. (only that div.child,not another div.child)

something like this in css.

```
.parent:hover .child{...}
```

---

I want do it because I want to use animate.css lib.

I want add animate class with hover.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `$('.child').hover(function(){$(this).addClass('yourClass');},function(){$(this).removeClass('yourClass');});` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
$( "div.psrent" ).hover(function() {
 $(this).find("span").addClass('childClass').removeClass('oldClass');//If you want to change span class inside div
 $(this).addClass('childClass').removeClass('oldClass');//If you want to change div class .if you dont want to remove old class just skip removeClass
});
```

Dont forget to put your code inside :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I used .hover() function from the JQuery doc [here](http://www.example.com/).
I didn't generate the list items dynamically but the idea is the same :

- select the hovered "parent" element
- add the "blue" class when the
  mouse enter the "parent" element
- remove it when the mouse leave
  it.

```js
$('.parent').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).addClass('blue');
  },
  function() {
    $(this).removeClass('blue');
  }
);
```

```css
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="parent">
    <span class="child">child1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <span class="child">child2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <span class="child">child2</span>
  </div>
</body>
```